# What happens when you don't use a metric in k-means?

Tags: algorithms, machine-learning, cluster

K-means is a clustering algorithm which works like this:

```
def kmeans(int k, Coordinate[] points):
    Step 1: initialize k cluster centers to any (distinct) coordinates
    Step 2: check which points are closest to which cluster centers
    Step 3: move the cluster centers so they are central to their nodes
            e.g. by taking the average coordinate
    Step 4: back to step 2 (with some stop criterion)
```

Usually, the Euclidean metric is used in Step 2. What happens when no metric,  but only a (symmetric) function $d: points \times points \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is used? Can k-means still produce meaningful results?

Answer (score 3):

You should use k-means when you have coordinates and a euclidian distance metric. Its not just the distance that matters - you need to reassign cluster centers. So if you have coordinates, why use something other than euclidian distance? If you don't have coordinates, you can't use K-means.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, you can use any function that has a property of a distance (symmetric, non-negative, triangle inequality) for clustering with k-means, such as Euclidean distance, Manhattan distance, $l_n$ norm, and so forth.  During each iteration, the cluster centers are assigned by the position that minimizes the sum of the distances to the points currently in its cluster.  The Euclidean metric is particularly simple for finding that new cluster center:  the center is the mean of the cluster points.  However, every proper metric will yield cluster centers that minimize the sum of the distances to all points in the cluster, though it might be just a bit more complicated to calculate this new center.

If your distance function isn't a true metric, then you can get meaningless results, and even non-termination of the algorithm.

Most sophisticated software supports different distance measures in clustering, e.g., *Mathematica*, in which `FindClusters` supports a user-defined `DistanceFunction`.

Comment: David, its good that Mathematica is so flexible, but K-means has a clear definition, and it uses coordinates to compute the cluster means. That's the "means" in K-means. If you don't have coordinates you use a different algorithm such a k-medoid. If you do have coordinates, using a distance measure other than Euclidian is like shooting yourself in the foot.

Comment: @randomsurfer:  I am the author of the world's leading book on pattern classification (translated into 3 languages), am a Fellow of the International Association for Pattern Recognition, have taught PR in leading universities, and published in the field widely.  The questioner is really asking for k-medoids.  Please explain why using non-Euclean metrics is "shooting yourself in the foot."  Then search Google Scholar for many papers and dissertations on k-means with non-Euclidean metrics (e.g., weighted), and software (even beyond Mma) that allows non-Euclidean metrics in "k-means" clustering.

Comment: David, no disrespect here, but Lloyd's original k-means is defined in terms of coordinates and L2, and I'm sorry, I consider the leading book on PR to be the one by Bishop, and defines k-means the same way. By shooting yourself in the foot I mean that if you have coordinates, but choose some non-metric for clustering, you might not even terminate!

Comment: @randomsurfer:  Please re-read my postings.  I never said to use a "non-metric" (as you claim) but instead "you can use any function that has a property of a distance."  No problems with termination.  The original question was explicitly about *extending* k-means, so any argument that extending the algorithm "isn't k-means" or "isn't Lloyd" is moot, and (thankfully) ignored by the authors I suggested you consult.  Last I looked, my book outsold Chris';  moreover, faculty that have seen my forthcoming 3rd ed. have given extraordinarily favorable reviews, and I hope you'll take a look at it too.

Comment: David, let's call it a truce :) The author of the original post wanted to use a non-metric in the classical k-means, hence my answer. There are many extensions, heck you can view EM for a gaussian mixture as a k-means extension. But to keep things clear in one's head its good to have crisp definitions, and only after that you can look at extensions, similarities and connections.